# How to use T4 with VS2015? (Microsoft.TextTemplating.targets file not found)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, t4

I just tried to open one of my projects with Visual Studio 2015 the first time, and it says:

> The importede project "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\TextTemplating\Microsoft.TextTemplating.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

The files do not exist on disk indeed. What kind of SDK do I have to install in order to use text templating with VS 2015?

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28803328/t4-template-in-vs-2015 it should be in since CTP6 ...

Comment: On another note: I have VS 2015 Enterprise Edition, so it should be no problem with insufficient features...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I have found the answer myself. One has to install the "[Modeling SDK for Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126259.aspx)", available [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48148).